How to get rid of the popup in vscode

Hi all, some hovering triggered this popup but it is not disappearing afterwards. Have you run into this issue before and how to get rid of it without closing vscode?
Thanks.
Help: About
Not sure what to try. It's not that I want to disable popups altogether - just want to get rid of this one.

This seems like a bug in VSCode. Does it keep happening if you restart VSCode?

It goes away but similar things might happen. I didn't want to restart as I was mid debugging. But that's what I did for this instance anyway..

If it's something that happens often, it might be an extension you're using? Or it's something you're doing that triggers the bug? I haven't been able to reproduce in my VSCode.

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. also, does it go away if you hover over the thing it titles again?

Thank you! No it doesn't go away as it's supposed to do. I had to close that session. Maybe just a random bug. It happened twice in the past month.
